# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined javascript arary

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jsp

I obtain a JSON like this. I want to obtain the elem tActivitats and copy to an array:

```
[
  {
    "identificador": "A462D996C3DDF4C94A3BF1A23EBF2906",
    "num_grup": 1,
    "activitats": "1",
    "tActivitats": [
      {
        "mostrIdioma": "S",
        "calendariWeb": "S",
        "nomActiv": "Visita Museu",
        "codiActiv": "1",
        "tipus": "S",
        "idioma": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For each element of json:

```
var tActivitatsArray = new Array();
$.post('../ServletJson', {
  elem: 'accesWeb',
  sessionId: "<%=sessionActual%>"
}, function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(t, elem) {
    //dostuff
    tActivitatsArray = elem.tActivitats;
    //dostuff
  });
});
```

Then I have a function where I pass the elem tActviitatsArray and I try to iterate and I get the error  Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
for (var i = 0; i < tActivitatsArray.length; i++) {
  console.log("test" + tActivitatsArray[i].nomActiv);
}
```

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Thats the console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); result:

```
[
   {
      "identificador":"1AE2886120F41BBC0F76567993EF76E0",
      "num_grup":1,
      "activitats":"1",
      "horari":"sessio_1_13_1200_0_1345",
      "total":8.5,
      "num_pers":"3",
      "tarifa":"tarifa_1_3_1",
      "preu":"8.5#1~0#1",
      "butaques":null,
      "nomSala":"",
      "numerada":"false",
      "promo":"",
      "referencia":"100249790",
      "dataVisita":"22/05/2020",
      "combinada":"",
      "article":null,
      "precioTemp":[
         {
            "codActiv":"1",
            "codTarifa":"1",
            "precio":"8.50",
            "dtePromo":"0",
            "dteEuro":"%",
            "total":25.5,
            "tipus":"normal"
         }
      ],
      "tActivitats":[
         {
            "mostrIdioma":"S",
            "calendariWeb":"S",
            "nomActiv":"Visita Museu",
            "codiActiv":"1",
            "tipus":"S",
            "idioma":"0"
         }
      ],
      "tTarifa":[
         {
            "codTarifa":"1",
            "nomTarifa":"General"
         },
         {
            "codTarifa":"1",
            "nomTarifa":"General"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "identificador":"1AE2886120F41BBC0F76567993EF76E0",
      "num_grup":2,
      "activitats":"1",
      "horari":"sessio_1_1_1000_0_1059",
      "total":8.5,
      "num_pers":"3",
      "tarifa":"tarifa_1_3_1",
      "preu":"8.5#1~0#1",
      "butaques":null,
      "nomSala":"",
      "numerada":"false",
      "promo":"",
      "referencia":"100249790",
      "dataVisita":"23/05/2020",
      "combinada":"",
      "article":null,
      "precioTemp":[
         {
            "codActiv":"1",
            "codTarifa":"1",
            "precio":"8.50",
            "dtePromo":"0",
            "dteEuro":"%",
            "total":25.5,
            "tipus":"normal"
         }
      ],
      "tActivitats":[
         {
            "mostrIdioma":"S",
            "calendariWeb":"S",
            "nomActiv":"Visita Museu",
            "codiActiv":"1",
            "tipus":"S",
            "idioma":"0"
         }
      ],
      "tTarifa":[
         {
            "codTarifa":"1",
            "nomTarifa":"General"
         },
         {
            "codTarifa":"1",
            "nomTarifa":"General"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: IS this for any particular value of  `i` ?

Comment: Last code block for loop must be inside the function $.post cuase need to resolve the promise before access the data

Comment: David is right. In case you can't do this for whatever the reason is, you can make a sync request with `$.ajax({...async: false...})` instead of the `$.post()` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Three things;

1. Check the `tActivitatsArray` is defined before you iterate.
2. Iterating after the value is initialized.
3. Make sure that`tActivitats` array is not `undefined` in response.

Comment: Yeah is inicializated. Is so weird becuase it prints the first elem and then says the error:
test Visita Museu
mainFunctions.js?v2.3:2633 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (mainFunctions.js?v2.3:2633)

Comment: So you get the first element, can you check that the second element is not undefined ..?,
Also, could you add this line

 if(Array.isArray(tActivitatsArray) {
 // your for iterate loop ... 
}

this will handle the error and also will tell you how many are printing

Comment: I have only one elem. It prints the first and then returns the undefined lenght error

Comment: hope you are doing something like this.. https://jsfiddle.net/bLh0y52r/2/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the back end is an ASP.NET server. I can tell by the `<%=sessionActual%>`.

In that case, the `$.post` success function will receive a json object `data` that contains a sub element `d` which holds the requested resources from the server.

Change this line:

```
$.each(data,function(t,elem) {
...
}
```

into:

```
$.each( data.d ,function(t,elem){ 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Logic says it should work if data is being received and properly translated to an array:

```js
var a = [
      {
        "mostrIdioma": "S",
        "calendariWeb": "S",
        "nomActiv": "Visita Museu",
        "codiActiv": "1",
        "tipus": "S",
        "idioma": "0"
      }
    ];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log("test: " + a[i].nomActiv);
}
```

```
test: Visita Museu
```

Could you log the output of `JSON.stringify(data)` in callback?
BTW, you are overriding tActivitatsArray in that `each` loop. You should push/merge instead of overriding the value. I think this is your idea, right?

Comment: Yes I want to translate the object to an array. Yes thats my idea.

Comment: @proera then you need to `tActivitatsArray.push(elem.tActivitats)` or `tActivitatsArray.concat(elem.tActivitats)`.

Comment: @proera update your post with the stringified output please so I can see the real returned value. Or just use "debugger;" to stop execution there and see the real type of a single element.

Comment: I have added the stringified output

Comment: @proera well, data is ok, so it must be an async issue. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930721/cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-javascript-arary/61931158?noredirect=1#comment109536544_61930721